# How do you get the OpenGL ADA bindings to be recognized by GNAT Programming Studio and ADAGide?

Tags: opengl, ada, gnat

I have been having some serious issues when it comes to use OpenGL and Ada, when it comes to learning how to access opengl calls in my ADA IDEs (which inclkudes GPS and ADAGide).
Every time I attempt to compile or build a program, I get an error message saying that "c:/openglada/lib" could not be found when I try to run or build a test.gpr that was included in the binding.

I get a similar error message when trying to compile in ADAGide saying that "opengl-gl/glut.ads could not be found, even though the folder is clearly ON my hard drive..

what do I need to do to correct this problem? I've been unable to get this fixed for almost four days now.
I'm working in Windows 7, 32-bit.

Comment: Did you read the instructions at https://github.com/flyx/OpenGLAda ? (you need to scroll down past the listing of the files)

Comment: OpenGLAda is the sort of library that is much much easier to use if you use the `.gpr` (GNAT Project) files that the author has provided. I don’t think AdaGIDE supports GPRs, does it? whereas GPS does. [Disclaimer: I don’t program with OpenGL, and I don’t use Windows for development]

Comment: no. ADAGide doesn't do gprs...

Answer (score 0):

When you use OpenGL (or any library) you have to think of it in two pieces the API binding and the actual binary library. Ignoring project files and make files, include the bindings in your source directory and a pragma that links your program to the binary library for OpenGL in windows (generally C:\Windows\System32). Your program will compile and you will have access to OpenGL functions.

Binding:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/adaopengl/files/adaopengl/adaopengl-0.12/adaopengl-0.12.zip/download

Link to binary:

```
pragma Linker_Options("/Windows/System32/opengl32.dll");
```

EDIT: If you are looking for a glut binary download, click on the "bin" link and use the same pragma above to link to dll in the download. The above bindings should have the glut bindings already. http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html

```
pragma Linker_Options("PATHTOGLUTDLL/glut32.dll");
```

Comment: I guess you missed the part where I mentioned that I have the adaopengl binding...

Comment: @user3843131 There are many ada opengl bindings and while they are all different and may or may not have extra features, they all do the same thing: connect to a binary library. I dont know which binding you were using, where that binding expected binary libraries to be, and how it was linking to them. I gave you an example on a binding you could download and how you could link with it - it would probably take 20 or 30 mins to test and confirm it works. Put the opengl.ads, opengl-glu.ads, opengl-glut.ads files in your source code directory and add the pragmas above to your main procedure file.

Comment: Just use .gpr files - far easier ;)